# Detecting molecules in space?

Tags: astronomy, spectroscopy, molecules, telescopes

http://www.forbes.com/sites/alexknapp/2012/02/24/nasa-detects-solid-buckyballs-in-space/

I refer to the above article, which mentions that buckyballs "far smaller than the width of a hair" were detected 6,500 light years from Earth. How do scientists manage to detect such small objects at such a distance, and what techniques do scientists use to identify them?

Answer (score 2):

One of the routine methods for detecting the presence of chemical compounds is [infrared spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_spectroscopy), and you'll find infrared spectrometers scattered around any terrestrial orgganic chemistry lab. Organic compounds absorb infrared light at characteristic frequencies, and those absorption lines can be used as a fingerprint to detect the molecule.

Exactly the same method is used to detect organic molecules in space. The [Spitzer telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spitzer_Space_Telescope) is an infrared telescope, and it can record infrared spectra such as this one:

[image: Buckyball spectra]

([see here for the original source](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/spitzer/multimedia/pia13287a.html) and [here for the corresponding article](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/spitzer/news/spitzer20100722.html))

that show the presence of Buckyballs (as well as the larger C$_{70}$ molecules).

This spectrum is actually from the 2010 detection of Buckyballs. The work you link is from 2012 and detects Buckyballs in an aggregated form. I can't find the spectra for this online, but the work is based on changes to the spectra caused by the moecules aggregating to form a larger particle.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for the concise explanation.